# How to add a tag for paragraph with dynamically generating ID using Java Program?

Tags: java, xml

I have one xml File, Xml code contain one paragraph without a tag name and tag attribute "Id". I need to generate a new Id dynamically. you can see inside a p tag two line inside it. But it not have **tag name and Id attribute**. Please Help me in this. Example: I need the line should be like first two line . **Code should be DOM**

```
 <p id ="271_line_1">My boy are play cricket </p>
 <p id ="271_line_2">to win the game. Where they are playing? </p>

 <ExampleProgram>
 <catalog>
 <book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <p class="paragraph " id="271__paragraph_8">
   My boy are play cricket
  <iline class="iline_list " id="271_iline_list_9" response="SAMPLE">
  <iline class="option " id="271_option_15" prefer="i1">SCHOOL</iline>
  <iline class="option " id="271_option_18" prefer="i2">GROUND</iline>
  <iline class="option " id="271_option_19" prefer="i4">HOME</iline>
  </iline>
  to win the game. Where they are playing?
  </p>
  </book>
  <book id="bk103">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
  </book>
  </catalog>
  </ExampleProgram>
```

Method change P tag: Now I can able to create a p tag and i can able to set attribute Id manually. But the new **p tag is not replacing the text in the parent p tag**. I want replace the old text and I want insert the Newly created p tag. I want create Dynamic Id instead of manual Id.

```
private static String createPTagId(Node someNode)  {
String Id ="271_line_"
    NodeList childs = someNode.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < childs.getLength();i++) {
        Node child = childs.item(i);
        if (child.getNodeType() == Document.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (child.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {

                     Value = child.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue();
                    System.out.println("Attribute Value :" + Value);
                    printElement(doc);
                }
            } else {
                createPTagId(child);
                }
         }
        if(child.getNodeName().equals("p") && child.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue().contains(Value)){

            Node nextNode = someNode.getFirstChild();
             System.out.println("1 "+child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
             System.out.println("2 "+child.getLastChild().getNodeValue());

             String strP= child.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().toString().trim();
             String strP1= child.getLastChild().getNodeValue().toString().trim();
            int k ;
             for( k=1;k<3;k++){
                     Id = Id.substring(0,Id.length())+k;
                    System.out.println(Id);
             }
             Element title = doc.createElement("P");
             title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strP));
             title.setAttribute("id",Id);
             nextNode.appendChild(title);
             Node nextNodes = someNode.getLastChild();
             Element title1 = doc.createElement("P");
             title1.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(strP1));
             title1.setAttribute("id",Id);
             nextNodes.appendChild(title1);

        }

        }
```

wrong output:

```
<catalog>
<book id="bk101">
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
 </book>
 <p class="paragraph " id="271__paragraph_8">
 My boy is play cricket
 <iline class="iline_list " id="271_iline_list_9" response="SAMPLE">
 <iline class="option " id="271_option_15" prefer="i1">wind</iline>
 <iline class="option " id="271_option_18" prefer="i2">cloth</iline>
 <iline class="option " id="271_option_19" prefer="i4">ribbon</iline>
 </iline>
 to win the game.  Where they are playing?
 ---<p id ="271_line_">My boy are play cricket </p>---
 ---<p id ="271_line_">to win the game. Where they are playing? </p>
 </p>
 <book id="bk102">
  <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
  <title>Midnight Rain</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
  an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
  of the world.</description>
 </book>
 </catalog>
```

I can create p tag but it is not placed again in the same place where i get it from. It get placed as a last child of parent **P** tag. And I cont able to create id attribute dynamically for created new P tag.

New xml:

```
<Liberary>
<booksInLiberary 
class="book_list_1" id="271_book_list_9"   response="bookInLiberary"> 
<p class="paragraph " id="271__paragraph_8">
The Science subject score got increase
<iline class="iline_list " id="271_iline_list_9" response="SAMPLE">
<iline class="option " id="271_option_15" prefer="i1">wind</iline>
<iline class="option " id="271_option_18" prefer="i2">cloth</iline>
<iline class="option " id="271_option_19" prefer="i4">ribbon</iline>
</iline>
,buy coming Exam. Pass percentage 35% increase?
</p>
</bookInLiberary>
<booksWithStudents 
class="book_list_2" id="271_book_list_9"  response="bookWithStudents">
<p class="paragraph " id="271__paragraph_8">
The Duke unvirsity students renew
<iline class="iline_list " id="271_iline_list_9" response="SAMPLE">
<iline class="option " id="271_option_15" prefer="i1">wind</iline>
<iline class="option " id="271_option_18" prefer="i2">cloth</iline>
<iline class="option " id="271_option_19" prefer="i4">ribbon</iline>
</iline>
the books to study for Exams
</p>
</booksWithStudents>
<Liberary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be useful to you. I think that the following are the issues with your code.

1. When you execute the statement "Id = Id.substring(0,Id.length())+k;", you are replacing the original string "271_line_".
2. When you add the new "P" tag, you don't replace the existing text child element.

The following code will do what you expect.

```
NodeList pnodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("p");
        for(int i=0;i<pnodes.getLength();i++){
            NodeList nodes = pnodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
            int k = 0;
            for(int j = 0;j<nodes.getLength();j++){
                if(nodes.item(j).getNodeName().equals("#text")){////Check if the current child element is a text node or not, if yes then replace it with the new P element
                    k++;
                    Element title = doc.createElement("P");
                     title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(nodes.item(j).getNodeValue()));
                     String tempId = Id + k; // generate the new Id
                     title.setAttribute("id",tempId);
                     pnodes.item(i).replaceChild(title, nodes.item(j)); // replace the child element, instead of appending
                }
            }
```

Comment: Now you directly taken a p tag using getElementByTagName(). But for example If i have a P tag in other Body3 tag it will be problem. I need to take Parent tag Body2 instead of P tag  and check for which sub child have a text  alone and does not have a tag Name or only Text.

Comment: If I understand your concern correctly, then there are some other tags for which you have to replace children nodes which are simple text elements. For that you can do the same handling as previously done for "P" elements.

Comment: See on top I given new xml: In that xml, I have Parent tag (Liberary) inside that it have 2 child tag (booksInLiberary) and(booksWithStudents)
I need to create a new tag with name (p) for text without tag name, which is inside the child tag (booksInLiberary). If I taken (P) tag using getElementbyTagName()
Commenly it will impact other unneed empty text without tag. I need to create (p) tag only for text inside in the bookInLiberary child tag.